# Rails Asset Pipeline Manifest: How to require a URL instead of a local file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my manifest I start by requiring jQuery and a few other libraries. Now I need to require a file from a CDN after jQuery, but before my local javascript. I can't find any documentation on this approach. How can I do this?

Comment: Why CDN, download the file and keep it inside the assets/javascripts folder and then require it

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would work. I was hoping to find a way to add a third-party javascript error reporting library at a certain load order in a way that didn't require me to maintain my own copy. Also, relying on a CDN download could potentially reduce the amount of JavaScript my users would need to download, assuming they've already downloaded this third-party library once before.